# Read js files after bundling in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a js file for configuration in the website. I use webpack from now, I couldn't find a way to get this kind of configuration file on webpack.  This webapp is an internal website and we deploy it in different VM's. I need this configuration file not get included inside of the bundle file and this must be read in the index.html

I tried dot.env but it only gets the env config files while bundling. That is not something I need. This config file can be changed depending on different deployment VM's.

What is the way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. Do you mean you need to read that "configuration file" from index.html without including it in the bundle?

Comment: Yes, the config file is like an external file because lets say VM1 needs `{logo:"logo1.png"}` and VM2 needs `{logo:"logo2.png"}` . These configs are specified in config.js and I want it to be read before app.bundle.js so I can use the variable `logo` in app.bundle.js. I will create or update this config.js after bundling and deploy